# Display on/off different areas of HTML

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

What I am trying to accomplish is being able to take a section of code / HTML and tell JSF to include it or not in the final render. I have messed around with the `<ui:remove>` tag, but that will always remove the contents.

Here is what I am trying to not include:

```
<li><h:commandLink value="Create an Account" action="createUser"/></li>
<li><h:commandLink value="Login" action="login"/></li>
```

I need something to wrap around this that will include it on a rendered = true/false basis. I want it to not include any bloated code like a div, table, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope I understand your question right, have you tried these components with **rendered** attribute?

Example:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.display}">
    <li><h:commandLink value="Create an Account" action="createUser"/></li>
    <li><h:commandLink value="Login" action="login"/></li>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGrid rendered="#{bean.display}">
    <li><h:commandLink value="Create an Account" action="createUser"/></li>
    <li><h:commandLink value="Login" action="login"/></li>
</h:panelGrid>

<rich:panel rendered="#{bean.display}">
    <li><h:commandLink value="Create an Account" action="createUser"/></li>
    <li><h:commandLink value="Login" action="login"/></li>
</rich:panel>
```

'display' is the boolean property defined in your JavaBean which you use to control the visibility of your XHTML code.

Another tag you can use is `<ui:include>`, it might help you better organize your code when the section of XHTML code is big enough to put in another .xhtml.

```
<ui:include src="yourPath.xhtml" rendered="#{bean.display}">
</ui:include>
```

For `<ui:remove>`, I usually use it to temporarily comment out the code as `<!-- XHTML code -->`.

Comment: I was under the impression that this would add extra code. After testing I can see that it does not.